# List item background colour doesn't change on an Ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, asp.net

I have a generic list which I had to implement after finding out about ListBoxes and apple products and or touch devices(I didn't test against android).

My list is like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>
<ul>
```

The list item tags are created and populated at runtime.

My Js/Jquery is as follows:

```
$('.List li').on('click touch', function () {
var selected;

selected = document.querySelector('li.selected');
console.log(selected);
if (selected)
    selected.classList = '';
this.classList = 'selected'

document.getElementById('ItemValue').value = this.id;
});
```

This works just how I want it to work on a computer, it selects the item and applies the css.

I've tested this on an Ipad and it **does** get selected but the css isn't applied. I know it gets selected because I can manipulate the items placement in the list after tapping the item.

I wouldn't like to set the background colour via Js/Jquery, I prefer adding a class and removing them when necessary.

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'colour')
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

***Additional notes:***

I've tried adding ':focus' to the selected class in the css, this didn't work on Ipad and computer.

*Edit_1:*

I've tried adding padding as suggested on a stackoverflow thread, however this didn't work.

*Edit_2:*

Tried a newer and more up to date Ipad, the problem still persists so I don't think it has anything to do with compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem on my own, simply use the remove and add methods of classList.

I replaced

```
selected.classList = ''; 
to:
selected.classList.remove('selected');

selected.classList = 'selected';
to:
this.classList.add('selected');
```

The following url helped me fix this issue :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList